# Limit amount of marks beetwen words except specific marks combination

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq, punctuation

I'm trying to keep in the string only one white-space between words, limit amount of repeated mark in the string for dot, comma, replace merged words with punctuation mark if it is between and keep it with white-space.

I want limit amount for all marks and keep only one between words with exception of question mark, if question mark before the dot, I want keep both, for example if input string is:

```
hello,,, world, how are you?.. hi...,.,.
```

now my result is:

```
hello, world, how are you? hi.
```

but desired output should be:

```
hello, world, how are you?. hi.
```

not sure how to do it

Comment: "?." in a sentance is really poor grammar, why would that be the right answer? your result would be correct - except Hi should be capitalised.

Comment: A question mark does not need a period after it, though?

Comment: Now, the output is as you need, have a look at [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs*%28%5c.%7c%2c%29%7b1%2c%7d%5cs*&i=hello%2c%2c%2c+world%2c+how+are+you%3f..+hi...%2c.%2c.&r=%241+) (click *Context* tab at the bottom).

Comment: @BugFinder Hello, this combination is not relevant to the grammar, it is needed for specific processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple solution could be

```
([.,])+|( )+
```

It matches comma or dot, and since it's in a capture group, the last instance get captured. Exchanging the match for the capture, will result in only one remaining.

**Edit** To handle multiple spaces, another capture group was added. It matches spaces, capturing the last. So exchanging match with both captures will handle both punctuation and spaces.

[See **the updated example** here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Zc7EeA/4).